# What information google extract from the crawled page?

Tags: search, search-engine, scrape, web-crawler

Google downloads the whole page by Crawling and then scrape some data to create the indexing like title, metatags?

What are the other datapoints google extracts from the page?

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html) old and classical paper from Google's founders:

System features include:

- Hyperlinks (for calculating pagerank)
- Anchor text
- Visual presentation details such as font size of words
- Full raw HTML of pages is available in a repository

Also see [this](http://www.prodigalwebmaster.com/2011/10/how-does-google-detect-duplicate-content/) for more about processing for information-retrieval purpose.